# Creating Corpus from wiki dump file using Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gensim, wiki, corpus

I'm trying to follow this page to create a wiki corpus, but I'm using Jupiter notebook https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/11/building-wikipedia-text-corpus-nlp.html

this is my code:

```
import sys
from gensim.test.utils import datapath
from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus

path_to_wiki_dump = datapath("enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2")

wiki = WikiCorpus(path_to_wiki_dump)

output = open('wiki_en.txt', 'w',  encoding='utf-8')

i = 0
for text in wiki.get_texts():
    output.write(bytes(' '.join(text), 'utf-8').decode('utf-8') + '\n')
    i = i + 1
    if (i % 10000 == 0):
        print('Processed ' + str(i) + ' articles')
output.close()
print('Processing complete!')
```

The Error I got was

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/test/test_data/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2'
```

All the files are in one place so I'm not sure what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ever download the file `enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2` somehow, somewhere?

Did you specifically place it at the path `/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/test/test_data/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2`?

If not the `datapath()` function you're using won't construct the right path. (That particular function is meant to find a directory of test data bundled with Gensim, and shouldn't really be used to construct paths to your own dowloaded/created files!)

Instead of using that function, you should just specify the *actual* path, local to the Jupyter notebook server, where you put the file, as a string argument to `WikiCorpus`.